# Remove optional parameter from AJAX url

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I want to make ajax URL dynamic, what I want is for `sub` and `nbr` parameters if they are equal to `All` or `null` pass only `org_id`.

How do I do this?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: baseURL + "/submitform/get/" + org_id + "/" + sub + "/" + nbr,
   success: function(res) {           
        parseJSON(res);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check them using `$.in_array` function:

```js
var baseURL = "baseURL";
var org_id = 111;
var sub = "All";
var nbr = null;
var conditions = ['All', null];
var url = baseURL + "/submitform/get/" + org_id;

if ($.inArray(sub, conditions) === -1 && $.inArray(nbr, conditions) === -1) {
  url += "/" + sub + "/" + nbr;
}

console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like this?

```
let url_to_send = `${baseURL}/submitform/get/${org_id}`;
if (sub === 'ALL') { // or 'ALL' if you meant a string rather than some declared value
    url_to_send +=  `/${sub}`
}
if (nbr === 'ALL') { // or 'ALL' if you meant a string rather than some declared value
    url_to_sned += `/${nbr}`;
}

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: url_to_send,
   success: function(res) {           
        parseJSON(res);
});
```

Put this in a function with parameters for nbr and sub, or however you're using it, and the url will be generated dynamically. Its how I usually go about it

You can also use template strings if you're using es6 and put ternary conditionals in them to generate your url that way right in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: `${baseURL}/submitform/get/${org_id}${(sub === 'ALL') ? `/${sub}` : ''}${(nbr === 'ALL') ? `/${nbr}` : ''}`,
       success: function(res) {           
            parseJSON(res);
    });
```

Comment: by ALL I mean string "All"

Comment: @JKLM Edited and I added a way to do it in one line if you want to keep everything in the ajax call